# Is setting state directly after each other bad?

Tags: reactjs

My scenario is:

```
this.setState({firstState:1})
if(condition){
  this.setState({secondState:2})
}
```

firsState should always be set to 1 but the secondState should only be set to 2 if a certain condition is fulfilled.

Is this bad practice because state will be updated twice directly after each other? And will it affect performance?

Is this code better?

```
if(condition){
  this.setState({firtState:1,secondState:2})
}else{
  this.setState({firstState:1})
}
```

Comment: Do you mind **when** state is updated before you go on with your process? If `condition` is `true`, `firstState` equals `1` and `secondState` still does not equal `2`, is it an inconsistent state for you?

Comment: Yes, second code is better.

Answer (score 2):

You can update it once:

```
const myAmazingState = {
  firstState: 1,
  secondState: condition ? 2 : this.state.secondState
}
```

And then update your state

```
this.setState({...myAmazingState})
```

Hope it makes sense

Comment: The question is about consequences of 2 sequential `setState` calls. Also, you should not use `this.state` inside a `setState` call. Use the callback instead.

Comment: @RaphaMex `this.state` is used when the `myAmazingState` object is constructed, not in the call to `setState`

Comment: No, I think using this.state inside of a set state is fine. It's the same as declaring it outside

Comment: @RaphaMex the idea is here - If you not sure about multiple `setState` method invocations sequentially, why not to use it only once?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: `this.state` properties are immutable. This code is fine, but awkward. Fine: if `secondState` is a reference, reference is kept so it does not trigger `render`; if it's a primitive (like here), value is equal so it does not trigger `render`. Awkward: in any case we make an assignment so that it does not render... So I prefer **OP**'s version.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you put multiple `setState` calls in sequence React may batch them into one transaction call.

So there is no disadvantage.

See [React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: `setState` is async, so this is not accurate.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Yes, doesn't change that it may be one transaction.

Comment: There is a disadvantage, if React decides to *not* batch them then your state is out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

React actually provides a way for you to achieve just that. The trouble with your current approach, as was pointed out earlier, is that React may batch the `setState`, but you can use functional `setState`. Your code would look like this.

```
this.setState((state, props) => {
  // update state
  if(condition) {
    //update state 2
  }

  // return a single new object for your new state
});
```

Answer (score 0):

React.js is optimized to have setState called quite often, it will actually not always re-render everytime you call setState but in fact will bundle multiple state changes together into one re-render.

In order to change the state twice, you need to do the following to avoid any possible issues as this.setState is an asynchronous function.

```
this.setState({data: {}}, () => this.setState({data: {name: "tom"}}))
```

Here you can see, we are passing setState a callback to execute once it has finished setting the state.